# most effective way using ExecutorService

Tags: java, executorservice

In my program I wrote a class, which updates a bunch of listeners every time when a new value is triggered. Therefor I am using a `SingleThreadExecutor`, the example should make it more clear. What I am worrying about is, does it make sense when I run it like that:

```
Class Update() {
    ExecutorService svc = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    svc.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(!theListeners.isEmpty()) {
                for(IgpsdListener l : theListeners) {
                    l.update(jsonObject);
                }   
            }
        }
    });
```

I heard, that creating Threads is quite expensive action in JAVA, so I am wondering if I am using it correctly. I mean, it creates every time a new `Runnable` object right? Even the Executor uses only the one and only thread.

Thanks in advance for any help and enlightenment.
nyyrikki

Comment: I would move `if(!theListeners.isEmpty())` to outside the execute().  There is no point adding a task which doesn't do anything.  I assume you are reusing your executor and not creating one for each task.

Comment: The executor is created only once, correct. What you mentioned makes completely sense, if I move the `if()` outside the `execute()` the task wouldn't even be executed in the case no listeners registered for the event. Didn't see that, nice...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what you're supposed to be doing. Java is quite fast at creating one-shot objects like this; threads might be expensive, but just creating a `Runnable` like you do here is cheap.

Comment: The runnable is cheap, the executor not.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine as far as the performance is concerned. You are not explaining what is the source of `jsonObject`, but if your `Runnable` is stateless, you might get away with creating only a single instance as well (probably not the case, but still worth to know).

For instance if this is your whole code:

```
class Update() {

    private final List<IgpsdListener> theListeners = //...

    private ExecutorService svc = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    svc.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(!theListeners.isEmpty()) {
                for(IgpsdListener l : theListeners) {
                    l.update();
                }   
            }
        }
    });
```

This can be simplified to:

```
class Update() {

    private final List<IgpsdListener> theListeners = //...

    private ExecutorService svc = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    final Notifier notifier = new Notifier()

    //execute this as many times as you want with the same notififer instance
    svc.execute(notififer);

    class Notifier implements Runnable {
            public void run() {
                if(!theListeners.isEmpty()) {
                    for(IgpsdListener l : theListeners) {
                        l.update();
                    }   
                }
            }
    }
```